# iPhone app network communication in background

Tags: iphone, networking, multitasking

Is it possible to have an iPhone app which carries on listening for data on a port when it is sent to background by the user and if any data comes the app can show a local notification and alert the user? I know the multitasking is deliberately limited but wof it allow for that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It can but with major caveats:

- First, the system will unregister any Bonjour names you might have established.
- Second, if you're bound to the WWAN, it will go down even with you listening on it (this is true even in the foreground).
- Third, if your app is not doing anything else in the background (i.e., isn't registered to provide background music, location events or telephony), you must still shutdown within the time limit for background task completion or be terminated.

So, while you could bind and listen on a socket in the background, for almost all practical purposes, it's not worth doing and you should rethink your design.

Answer (score 2):

This is exactly what push notifications are for.  Your application doesn't listen to your server, your server tells Apple's about any notifications, and Apple's server delivers them to the user and your application *if the user wants them*.

Comment: Yes I know but that means having my own server.

Comment: By network I meant a local network with a computer running software to send data to the devices ip address (found by bonjour)

Comment: Supporting push notifications does mean having your own server, yes.  Again, that's by design:  You can't have an app polling a server or listening for connections in the background.  Your app can be launched in response a push notification if the user decides they want to receive them.